# setting up postgresql/constantly giving me error could not connect to server:

Tags: django, postgresql

Hello I'm trying to use postgresql, on my digital ocean provided server.
I did `$ sudo apt-get install postgresql` then `$ sudo su postgres` then `$ createuser -P djangousr` but then now I get an error:

> createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect
>   to server: No such file or directory
>   Is the server running locally and accepting
>   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I googled around but just couldn't find a solution. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does `sudo service postgresql start` help?

Comment: @AlexMorozov it asks for postgresql password but I never set any password that It\s [sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.

Comment: Try running `dpkg-reconfigure postgresql`, your configuration seems to be broken somehow .

Comment: @AlexMorozov it returns locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure must be run as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you install the server, you have to configure it - it should have prompted to configure it for you. If it didn't, run the following command to reset the installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Once they finish, then follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04). To test if everything is working, the following commands should get you to the postgresql shell:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
```

Use `\q` to quit the shell.

Comment: yeah that's the tutorial I'm following I get the above error when I run psql

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this error, too. Try this command

```
ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

This worked out for me... Hope that helps!

Comment: sadly it doesn't work...it asks for password for new rule twice and the same error....also I've never set any password for postgres but it asks for one when I try other things